# How to convert rows to JSON in TSQL select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql

Following query returns whole table as single JSON string (list of JSON objects - one per row):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable FOR JSON AUTO
```

I need to return multiple rows where each row will be a JSON string of a signle row of the table.

For example if table fields are A,B,C output should be:

```
{A: <value>, B: <value>, C: <value>}
{A: <value>, B: <value>, C: <value>}
{A: <value>, B: <value>, C: <value>}
...
{A: <value>, B: <value>, C: <value>}
```

**How to do this in TSQL ?**

While it's possible to construct JSON strings by hand by concatenating strings, I'd prefer to reuse existing tool that would handle cases like quotes in values.

Comment: Are you using SQL server 2016?

Answer (score 31):

This will return json data in rows from a select statement.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(Max)
SET @json = (SELECT * FROM [Sales].[Customers] FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data'))
SELECT value
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.data');
```

Comment: Openjson is available only in sql server 2016,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql

Comment: For JSON AUTO started in 2016 as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server.

Comment: you also never specified a version

Comment: This just saved me from pages of code for dynamically parsing columns to JSON.
Thank you :)

Comment: `SET @json = (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = @value FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);` In case you do not need 'data' as wrapper and include nulls

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone else stumbles on this.
Similar to @Waldemar but without the need for the self join in the correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT (SELECT A, B, C FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)
FROM MyTable
```

The columns A, B and C are coming from the "MyTable" in the FROM, rather than needing a second reference and an implicit self join.

Comment: Thank you especially for WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER option!

Answer (score 3):

You can transform a record to a JSON object, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable  
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Comment: it is about each row no all result.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
SELECT JTBL.* FROM MyTable A
CROSS APPLY ( select A, B, C from MyTable B WHERE B.ID = A.ID FOR JSON AUTO ) JTBL (JSTXT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT (
  SELECT ID, A, B, C, D
  FROM MyTable t1
  WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) AS column_name
FROM MyTable t2
```